# Handle recipes and ingredients with CakePHP 3 / MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I made a post about recipes and ingredients but infortunately my post was not enough clear, so I try to be more clear in this one.

I have two SQL table :

```
PRODUCTS (id, code, name)
RECIPES (product_id, ingredient_id, qty)
```

product_id and ingredient_id are both id's of the table PRODUCTS. A "final" product can be compound by sub-products.

I want to display all recipes needed to make a recipe in one view, with a tree view.

I will do an example, for this, we can have a database extract like that :

```
PRODUCTS (id is auto_increment)

  code  |      name      |
________|________________|
   A    |  Product A     |
   A1   |  Product A1    |
   A2   |  Product A2    |
   A21  |  Product A21   |    
   A22  |  Product A22   |
   A3   |  Product A3    |

             RECIPES

  product_id | ingredient_id | qty |
_____________|_______________|_____|
      A      |      A1       |  5  |
      A      |      A2       |  9  |
      A      |      A3       |  11 |
      A2     |      A21      |  2  |
      A2     |      A22      |  3  |
```

For example, to make 10 Products A, I want display this :

```
Product A - 10
--> Product A1 - 50 (5*10)
--> Product A2 - 90 (9*10)
------> Product A21 - 180 (2*(9*10))
------> Product A22 - 270 (3*(9*10))
--> Product A3 - 110 (11*10)
```

I can just display a list of ingredients (A1, A2, A3) but I can't display all sub-recipes like A21 and A22 for the Product A2.

I'm doing this in my controller :

```
$ingredients[] = [$codeProduct=> $this->Recipes->getListOfIngredients($codeProduct)];
```

The getListOfIngredients function :

```
public function getListOfIngredients($code = null){
        if ($code <> null){
             $ingredients = $recipes->find('all', ['conditions' => ['Recipes.product_id = ' => $code]]);
             return $ingredients->toArray();
        }
    }
```

With that code, `$ingredients[]` contains all ingredients for a product, but how can I add all sub-recipes ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You had better show us some code or this question is going to get downvotes and closed

Comment: @RiggsFolly I edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

Using below query you will get all records for `Product A`.

```
Select * from RECIPES r inner join  RECIPES r1 on r.ingredient_id = r1.product_id and r.product_id = 'A'
```

Then you have to loop that array to produce tree structure.

Comment: Is it possible to add on my SELECT a kind of " COUNT () " to know if (in your example) r.product_id = 'A' have sub recipes or not ?